# Symfony: get file in controller from web folder

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get pdf file from web folder in controller, but can't figure out how to do it.

I've try to get path like this

```
// 1
$file = __DIR__ . '/../../../../web/1.pdf';  

// 2
$file = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'\..\web\1.pdf';

// 3
$isSecure = $request->isSecure() ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$file = $isSecure . $request->getHost() . $this->container->get('assets.packages')->getUrl('1.pdf');
```

and then use [file controller helper](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-file-controller-helper) but it didn't work.

How can I get that file from public directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

Append this to autoload.php

```
define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(__DIR__) . '/');
define('WEB_PATH',  APPLICATION_PATH . '../web/');
```

also you can add another folders

Then

```
file_get_content(WEB_PATH . 'your_file.pdf');
```

Another way -

```
$path = $this->getParameter('dir.downloads');
```

But don't forget to declare it on parameters.yml like this

```
parameters:
    ....
    dir.downloads: var/www (your folder)
    ....
```